# How run this applications on Flet framework

Tags: python, django-views, flet

## Describe

Hello guys i want to create something like pattern for creating applications on Flet
And I ran into a problem.

## Structure of project

```
├───app
│   ├───utils
|   |   └-----handler.py
│   ├───views
|   |    └-----test_view.py
|   └---app.py
├───second_app
│   ├───utils
|   |   └-----handler.py
│   ├───views
|   |    └-----test_view.py
|   └---second_app.py
└---main.py
```

This is a pre structure for pattern
The idea is that there will be several applications, for example, for logging in, the main application, and so on, just like in django.
Each application has folders `utils`, `views`, main_app.py

#### Utils

On `utils` folder of course, utilities and various auxiliary tools
Example the event handler

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from app.app import App


class Handler:
    def __init__(self, _app: App) -> None:
        self.app = _app

        self.app.button.on_click = lambda _: self.button_click()

    def button_click(self) -> None:
        print("App button clicked")
```

#### Views

On 'views' our views with the already written code that we need to display
Example:

```py
from flet import View, Text, ElevatedButton


class TestView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        self.route = "/test"
        self.button = ElevatedButton("click_me")

        self.controls = [Text("Tested veiw", size=20, color="black"), self.button]
```

#### main_app.py

```py
from flet import Page, TemplateRoute, RouteChangeEvent, ElevatedButton

from app.views.test_view import TestView


class App:
    def __init__(self, page: Page):
        self.page = page

        self.test_view = TestView()

        self.views = {self.test_view.route: self.test_view}

        self.page.on_route_change = self.route_change

    def route_change(self, _e: RouteChangeEvent) -> None:
        template_route = TemplateRoute(self.page.route)
        self.page.views.clear()

        for route, view in self.views.items():
            if template_route.match(self.page.route):
                self.page.views.append(view)
                break

    @property
    def button(self) -> ElevatedButton:
        return self.test_view.button
```

And some thing like this on the second of application

#### main.py

This file shoud be something like 'connecting' file, which will combine all applications and start the Flet app

## Problem

Earlier i was running only one app and code of `main.py` file was like this

```py
import flet as ft

from app.app import App
from second_app.second_app import SecondApp


def main():
    ft.app(target=App)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And now when i need run two more applications how do I implement this?

Or are there some good solutions

## Main idea

Idea is that use pattern of MVT on Flet like on django

How run this project like django project but on Flet